# How to test the image is following gaussian distribution or not in opencv

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I need to test image intensity(Grayscale image) is following Gaussian distribution or not without visualization using the histogram.

I need to define a function as below.

```
def isGuassianDistrubution(img):
#If it follows Gaussian distribution returns true else returns false
 pass
```

What can I do, plz assists me?

## What I tried so far

I have done the Shapiro-Wilk Test for sobel operators columns and rows

1. Got SobelX, and SobelY of the image
2. each row of the operator, I have checked that it passes the Shapiro-Wilk test or not.
3. I count the rows which are passed in the test
4. The same thing has been done for columns of the operator
5. I get the ratio of test passes row / total rows and test passes cols/ total cols

***I am thinking to take if any of the ratios is greater than 0.5 then I may decide the image is following the Gaussian distribution***. **Please correct me If it wrongs**

```py
from scipy.stats import shapiro

def get_sobel_operators(img_path):
  img = cv2.imread(img_path,0)
  # laplacian = cv.Laplacian(img,cv.CV_64F, ksize =3)
  sobelx = cv.Sobel(img,cv.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
  sobely = cv.Sobel(img,cv.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)
  return sobelx,sobely

def test_guassian(arr):
  # generate univariate observations
  # normality test
  stat, p = shapiro(arr)
  print('Statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
  # interpret
  alpha = 0.05
  if p > alpha:
      print('Sample looks Gaussian (fail to reject H0)')
      return True
  else:
      print('Sample does not look Gaussian (reject H0)')
      return False


def guassian_intensity_ratio(img):
  rows,columns = img.shape
  print(rows,columns)
  print(len(img))
  gaussian_rows = 0
  guassian_cols = 0
  for row in img:
    if test_guassian(row):
      gaussian_rows = gaussian_rows+1
  for col in img.T:
    if test_guassian(col):
      guassian_cols = guassian_cols+1
  guassian_row_ratio =float((gaussian_rows)/rows)
  guassina_col_ration =float((guassian_cols)/columns)
  return guassian_row_ratio,guassina_col_ration
    
def get_sobel_operators_guassian_ratio(image_path):
  sobelx, sobely = get_sobel_operators(image_path)
  sobel_x_row_ratio, sobel_x_col_ratio =guassian_intensity_ratio(sobelx)
  sobely_row_ratio, sobel_y_col_ratio = guassian_intensity_ratio(sobely)
  return {"sobel_x_row_ratio":sobel_x_row_ratio, "sobel_x_col_ratio":sobel_x_col_ratio,  "sobely_row_ratio":sobely_row_ratio, "sobel_y_col_ratio":sobel_y_col_ratio}
```

My sample Images

v2.png - > [image: Not a guassian distrubution img]

v.png -> [image: Guassian distrubution img]

Results

```
#v.png image result
{'sobel_x_col_ratio': 0.3851851851851852,
 'sobel_x_row_ratio': 0.5925925925925926,
 'sobel_y_col_ratio': 0.6296296296296297,
 'sobely_row_ratio': 0.28888888888888886}


#v2.png result 
{'sobel_x_col_ratio': 0.1848341232227488,
 'sobel_x_row_ratio': 0.13744075829383887,
 'sobel_y_col_ratio': 0.3459715639810427,
 'sobely_row_ratio': 0.11374407582938388}
```

Comment: Please share what you tried so far.

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle I have added what I tried. I hope you will help me to solve this prb

Comment: Sorry @fmw42. I have added details clearly now. please check. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "image intensity is following Gaussian distribution"? Do you want to know if the histogram of the image looks like a Gaussian, if the image contains a Gaussian bell in it, if the noise is Gaussian, ...?

Comment: Chris, I need to know the gradient of the image is having a Gaussian distribution or not.